# Blender: How can I exclude an object from another?

Tags: blender

Blender: How can i exclude an object from another so that I'm left with an object with holes in it?

I'm currently trying to create a 3.951x2.610x0.05 box with holes across it. The holes are 0.1x0.1x0.5. I select them all but I don't know how to exclude them from the box

Comment: I think this question better suits http://blender.stackexchange.com

Comment: You may want to use the [boolean modifier](http://blender.stackexchange.com/questions/18545/boolean-modifier-trouble)

Answer (score 0):

The hole height should be the same as box height, right?
Say it's both 0.5 in below example script:

```
import bpy

epsilon = 10e-5
bpy.ops.mesh.primitive_cube_add()
bpy.ops.transform.resize(value=(3.951,2.610,0.5))
obj_A = bpy.context.object
bpy.ops.mesh.primitive_cube_add()
bpy.ops.transform.resize(value=(0.1,0.1,0.5+epsilon))
obj_B = bpy.context.object

bpy.ops.object.select_all(action='DESELECT')
bpy.context.scene.objects.active = obj_A

obj_modifier = obj_A.modifiers.new('myBoolModifier', 'BOOLEAN')
obj_modifier.object = obj_B
obj_modifier.operation = 'DIFFERENCE'
bpy.ops.object.modifier_apply(apply_as='DATA', modifier="myBoolModifier")
bpy.context.scene.objects.unlink(obj_B)
```

The output:
[image]